# How can i make a class Immutable if it has a instance variable of java.lang.Object?

Tags: java, immutability

```
final public class ImmutableWithObject {

    final Object obj;
    final List myList;

    ImmutableWithObject(Object obj1, List list)
    {
        this.obj = obj1;
        this.myList = ((List) ((ArrayList) list).clone());
    }

    public Object getObj() {
        return this.obj;
    }

    public List getMyList() {
        return (List) ((ArrayList<String>) this.myList).clone();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ImmutableWithObject io = new ImmutableWithObject(new Date(), new ArrayList());

        ((Date) io.getObj()).setDate(22);

        System.out.println((Date) io.getObj());
    }
}
```

```
o/p : Mon Aug 22 00:50:04 IST 2011
```

which is incorrect.

Comment: Do you intend to expose the Object after creation?  (ie, a getObj() method?)

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on your question so it is clear what you really want to prevent (protection of internal state, information hidding, encapsulation).

Comment: I've posted the whole code . now the question is to make this class immutable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make it immutable since this object cannot create copies of the contents of the list or the Object.  Assuming that you mean to have getters for accessing those properties, the properties themselves were created elsewhere and can be changed in code external to this class that has a reference to it.

The only exception to this is if the contents of Object and List are themselves immutable.  Then you can create an immutable copy of the list and you would be done.

Answer (score 6):

Immutable means that once the object has been constructed, its state does not change.

- Make class final ( which you have already done )
- Make the instance variables as private and final
- Dont provide methods that change the state
- When passing instance variables, send copies instead of original.

From EJ Item 15 <-- *Lot more information in there*

**Classes should be immutable unless there's a very good reason to make them mutable. If a class cannot be made immutable, limit its mutability as much as possible.**

Comment: Common sense should be applied instead.

Comment: If the class is final, then private and final won't make a difference (as long as they are not public).  To make it immutable, you have to only accept immutable classes as parameters to the constructor, or copy them in the constructor.  If mutable classes are passed in there is no way to guarantee immutability.

Comment: @Robin -- if the fields are protected or package-private, then other classes in the same package can obtain a reference to it and modify it. Its necessary to mark them as final also because otherwise you could have trouble when passing objects between threads without synchronization.

Comment: Robin you are correct , but there should be some generic way to make a copy of Object type.

Comment: @Robin, not true. If the private field will be used by multiple threads, then some sort of concurrency visibility mechanism must be used. Making a field final allows all threads to see the same state. Other choices are synchronize and volatile.

Comment: @amicngh There isn't. (Which makes sense, when you think about it, what if your object represents a socket?) You can make a copy of `Cloneable` objects, but even that will only be a shallow copy.

Comment: @Steve Kuo - If the fields cannot change once the object is created, how will other threads see any other state?  It will be created in a single thread and if passed to others the internal state will always be consistent as no thread can change it.  I don't claim to be an expert, but I don't see how threading is an issue because of the final keyword.  If the properties are private, no state change can occur.

Comment: @Kal - You are correct, it does need to be private, I should have realized that before I posted.  I still think your last point is wrong though, it should be edited to create copies internally or take immutable objects as parameters.

Comment: @Robin -- Take a look at JLS 17.5 ( http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html ) ... It essentially has to do with the constructed object being in a state where is not fully constructed that crosses threads.

Comment: But my question is still there. Can we make ImmutableWithObject class immutable ?

Comment: @amicngh No. Since there's absolutely no restriction of what an Object can be, if you want immutable classes, don't use Objects as members.

Comment: so can say except Object we cab use any object as member to  make Immutable class but the restriction is that we need to work on the copies of those objects?

Answer (score 1):

Make the member variables private final and copy the parameters:

```
final class ImmutableWithObject {

    private final Object obj;
    private final List myList;

    public ImmutableWithObject(Object obj1 , List list)
    {
       this.obj = obj1.clone();
       this.list = (List) list.clone();
    }
}
```

This will not allow any other class to change your internal state and will not allow ImmutableWithobject to change the `myList` or `obj` references. *However* the obj's state as well as the list can still be manipulated internally. As others pointed out, whoever past the list or obj1 to you class, would be able to manipulate it from the outside too. Since there is no equivalent of something like `const` in C++, we will have to copy the objects to make sure they are not changed from the outside.

Similarly, if there was a getter, it should also only return a copy (or some read-only interface or a read-only wrapper):

```
 public Object getObj() { return obj.clone(); }
```

Comment: However, that does not make the `List` immutable.

Comment: first thing the problem in this is when this object is instantiated at that time you  could use java.util.Date as object.

Comment: This adds nothing to the defined class with respect to mutability since there is no way of changing those properties anyway.

Comment: There is no way to make the `List` instance immutable anyway (`obj`  neither). However, I changed the access modifiers so at least it cannot be changed externally and the interface can ensure immutability.

Comment: @Robin: Ok, I see what the original poster might be looking for now.

Comment: @inflagranti: I was just pointing that out incase the OP thought that was the case. Either way, you just provide an immutable implementation of a List:  http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html

Comment: To me the original question was very ambigious and I interpreted it wrong first. Should have asked to clarify.

Comment: You mean the object is not clonbale (does not implement Clonbale)?

Comment: no, i mean clone() method is protected in Object class and hence we can't make this call in our class

Comment: Doesn't  Collections.unmodifiableList() make the list immutable?.always return a unmodifiable list whenever the list instance is accessed.

Comment: It's funny that clone() is protected, as it can be accessed from any class, since any class inherits from Object. But it can however throw wan exception if clone() is not implemented for the specific class.

Comment: because you can call them as super.clone(). that calls Objects clone method.

Comment: That you could also do if they were public, which was what I was aiming at: I cannot think of a scenario where there is a difference between a public and a protected method in java.lang.Object. But maybe I'm overlooking something, could be a difference in a static context.

Comment: @firefox784 Collections.unmodifiableList makes the list unmodifiable (an exception is thrown for add and remove methods).   The list itself is only immutable if the elements within the list are immutable.  Imagine an unmodifable list of java.util.Date

Answer (score 1):

You can make a copy of the values of the List object. Whoever called it still has that List and can modify it.